# Create Dynamic Json on the go in expression functions inside mapping data flow (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: json, mapping, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I am trying to convert a csv file into json schema based collection. For json conversion, the only way I found was creating subcolumns for a column if you want hierarchy, Or you can use expressions like @(key1=value, @(key2=value2)) for json structures. What I want to do is Either  pick key1 or key2 as parameters from dataflow/pipeline Or use it in a loop over an array such as map(array,@(#item=#item+2)).
But It restricts me from doing that. However, I am able to traverse over values, But keys are something that needs to be only hardcoded. Please suggest a workaround if any.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

> 1: You can import the csv file into Azure SQL Database by using [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal)
> 2: Then you can [work with JSON features in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/json-features)